# SUM second and third LARGEST numbers out of previous 5 numbers

Tags: mysql, excel, set, updates

I am looking for a solution to UPDATE (compute the SET values) an existing table with the sum of 2nd and 3rd largest numbers of the previous 5.

```
ID   |  Price  |  Sum                                  |
     |         |  (2nd + 3rd largest of the previous 5)|
-------------------------------------------------------
1    |   6     |                                       |
2    |   1     |                                       |
3    |   8     |                                       |
4    |   3     |                                       |
5    |   5     |                                       |
6    |   9     |   should be 11                        |
7    |   1     |   should be 13                        |
8    |   6     |   should be 13                        |
9    |   6     |   should be 11                        |
10   |   9     |   should be 12                        |
11   |   2     |   should be 15                        |
12   |   4     |   should be 12                        |
```

In EXCEL, it is doable by: =LARGE(range,2)+LARGE(range,3) where range always points to the last 5 numbers.

I am aware MYSQL has the functions GREATEST(value1,value2,...) and LEAST(value1,value2,...), but this function only return the GREATEST or the LEAST value.

How do I make this challenge work if I need to IGNORE the 1st greatest number and add up only the 2nd and 3rd largest instead?

The thought goes around the principle:

```
UPDATE table 
    SET SUM = 
         GREATEST(2nd max price) where ID between ID-5 AND ID-1
         + 
         GREATEST(3rd max price) where ID between ID-5 AND ID-1
```

Comment: Did `ID` type = number and always sequence?

Comment: Yes, ID = int and always in sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this. I hope this is what you want.

```
update yourtable,
(
    select id,sum(number) as sum from(
        select id,number,
        case id when @id then @rownum := @rownum+1 else @rownum := 1 and @id:= id end as r
        from(
            select t.id,t1.number
            from yourtable t
            join(
                select id,number from yourtable order by number desc
                ) t1 on t1.id between (t.id - 5) and (t.id - 1)
            where t.id > 5
            order by t.id asc, t1.number desc
        ) t2
        join (select @rownum:=0, @id:=0) as x
    )as t3 where r in(2,3) -- 2nd max + 3rd max.
    group by id
)tab
set yourtable.sum = tab.sum
where yourtable.id = tab.id
```

This query `update` column `SUM` on yourtable with `(2nd Greater + 3rd Greater) from 5 previous  ID`. But if you want to view result only without update, just remove `UPDATE` statement.

p.s : `Number` on that query means `price` on your table.

Comment: Thank you, RubahMalam, will give this a try now.

Comment: Works brilliantly!! Your code is flexible and meets all my criteria!!! Thumbs up!!